# Remove cms block from only cms home page

Tags: magento2, layout, home-page

I have created a cms block and using widget added inside header page container, now I want to remove that block from only home page.

How can i achieve this?

Widget screenshot to display block

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to

> Admin -> Content -> Pages -> Edit CMS page (which you want to update) -> Design -> Layout Update XML

And then, post this below code in that field

```
<referenceContainer name="content.top">
   <referenceBlock name="form.popup.subscribe" remove="true"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

You can set name of **referenceContainer** and **referenceBlock** name which you want to remove.

**Hope, It will helpful for you  !!**

Answer (score 0):

**From Layout file:**

Goto app/design/frontend/[VendorTheme]/[ThemeName]/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml and add below code. BlockName will be the name of block which you want to delete.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
   <!-- add this code for remove block -->
   <referenceBlock name="BlockName" remove="true"/>
 </body>
 </page>
```

Comment: I implement this but not working

Answer (score 0):

Into the CMS home page, Design ->  Layout Update XML

```
<referenceBlock name="BlockName" remove="true"/>
```

save the cms page and clear the cache.

without xml you want to hide them using css display none.

Comment: i get following error 'Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'referenceBlock': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move, head, body ). Line: 1'

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you put the following code:

```
<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
```

in the **Design** >> **Layout Update XML** section of your CMS Home page in the admin panel.

After that, you just need to flush Magento's cache.

Since Magento provides to update the layout of CMS pages from the backend, there is no need to do it using the layout files.

**Update:**
[image: widget xml generated on save widget]

I hope it is clear.

Comment: i get following error 'Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'referenceBlock': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move, head, body ). Line: 1'

Comment: Also, If i add block id in name will it work

Comment: @Arjun, you are right. I noticed your point now. This is happening because while adding a widget to the pages, Magento generates the block name dynamically.

Comment: When we try to print the generated XML after saving the widget instance, we get the block name as a random string. Please check the screenshot in my answer's update.

Comment: ok i got your point so what do you suggest how can i remove this block only on home page or else i should remove widget

Comment: I think after saving the widget from the backend, it saves the layout update XML for the widget in layout_update table. It should give some clue here.

Comment: It is working by adding the random string that was generated as name in the layout table by adding remove='true' attribute in admin update layout. May be this is not the right way but working if the string doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

create below file

> app/design/frontend/name/example/Magento_CMS/layout/cms_index_index.xml

`<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>`

add below code and add your static **block_name**
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I implement this but not working